# ASP.NET Web API get user identity in controller constructor

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Is good idea to get user identity in ASP.NET Web API controller constructor, for example:

```
public PagesController(PageValidator pageValidator, PageMapper pageMapper, PagesManager pagesManager, UsersManager usersManager)
            :base(usersManager)
        {
          _pageValidator = pageValidator;
          _pageMapper = pageMapper;
          _pagesManager = pagesManager;
          if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            _pagesManager.UserId = usersManager.GetByEmail(User.Identity.Name).Id;
        }
```

Is always User.Identity was correct populated before this call raise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use this property in Controller in any place. ASP.NET has request pipeline: (http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/888/aspnet-webapi-message-lifecycle).
As you can see Authorization is early stage step in request pipeline. 
Controller creation is the latest stage.

Comment: Controller creation is not the latest stage; controllers are created prior to to the filters, and the controller *method* is accessed after

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But filter is additional request pipeline which not related to ASP.NET pipeline. Also after creation controller you can add logic in your action method which can validate request and so on...

Comment: The question was "is it a good idea" and the answer is no. The OP doesn't say *how* authentication is being performed. Irrespective of whether it's done by the host or by a filter, the identity is still accessed the same way; which means if you decide to change authentication mechanisms at some point, you will break your controllers in weird and wonderful ways.

Comment: Further OP goes on to ask "Is always User.Identity was correct populated"... and the answer to that is no also... not all authentication mechanisms populate that prior to controller construction.

Comment: I afraid you are confusing Authentication and Authorisation concepts.

Comment: I haven't even mentioned authorization, so I'm not sure how I'm confused by it. The only thing User.Identity has to do with authorization is that it needs to be populated (i.e. by authentication) before you can authorize anything. Nonetheless, it has nothing to do with the OP question.

Comment: This answer seems incorrect. At the controller's creation, `User.Identity` (nor `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`) is not yet available. It isn't null though, but an unauthenticated identity. So the check `if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)` is never going to work (IMHO).

Answer (score 5):

This has bitten me a few times. Depending on where/how you are performing your authentication, you need to be careful where you access your identity, **particularly** in controller constructors.

For example, whilst the controller **action** is invoked AFTER an `IAuthenticationFilter` is instantiated, the controller's **constructor** is called **before** `AuthenticateAsync`; meaning any authentication you do in `AuthenticateAsync` will not be available in your controller's constructor (like in your example).

I typically don't rely on things being available during controller construction (unless handled by DI). Instead access the identity as you need it in your controller actions.

If you are looking at making identity lookup easier (i.e. pulling in your user object based on the `User.Identity.Name` property) create a base controller class that has a property or method that does it for you, then have your controllers inherit from that...

```
public User AuthenticatedUser
{
    get
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return usersManager.GetByEmail(User.Identity.Name);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

See [here](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) for a detailed breakdown of the Web.API lifecycle, showing controller creation occurring prior to authentication.

Comment: return usersManager.GetByEmail(User.Identity.Name); - this code can populate Null reference exception.

Comment: That's right; just the same as it can when called in the constructor when User.Identity hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Not the same. There is check: if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

Comment: As it was intended as a simple example, I assumed that the OP would fill out the function; but I've edited it just in case anyone else isn't as pedantic